Pydantic @field_validator with mode before does not run
I'm using Pydantic v2 to validate. The raw input field rent_plan_id is a string, I want to convert it int before running any others validations. I configured as bellow but it seemed like the validation is not executed, I always received this error Input should be a valid integer, unable to parse string as an integer
In controller
@machine_router.get("/{machine_id}/check-balance")
async def check_can_rent_machine(
    machine_id: int,
    query: CheckCanRentMachineRequest = Depends(CheckCanRentMachineRequest),
):
    # Do something

Model validator
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator

class CheckCanRentMachineRequest(BaseModel):
    rent_plan_id: int | None

    @field_validator("rent_plan_id", mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def test(cls, raw: str):
        if not raw:
            return raw

        if not raw.isdigit():
            raise ValueError('rent_plan_id must be int')

        return int(raw)

    model_config = {
        "json_schema_extra": {
            "examples": [
                {
                    "rent_plan_id": 1,
                }
            ]
        }
    }

